# How to create a text field one by one on every click of a button?

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, uibutton, uitextfield

Here is my task..
How it is working now ?
If i click over the button, I am getting 5 text field one by one. But i want to create a text field on every click of a button.

Eg: First click should create 1st text field
    Second Click should create 2nd text field
    Third Click should create 3rd text field
    Fourth Click should create 4th text field
    Fifth Click should create 5th text field

Here is my code :

```
- (IBAction)button_click:(id)sender
{
float xaxis = 60;
float yaxis = 130;
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xaxis,yaxis,200,30)];
    textField.tag = i;
    textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    [self.view  addSubview:textField];
    yaxis = yaxis+50;
}}
```

[image: How it is working now]

Comment: If you only want to add one button per click, why do you use a loop to create 5 per click?

Comment: Because i have to create only 5 textfield ..

Comment: But you only want one added each time the button is tapped, right? Then get rid of the loop.

Comment: Okay I removed..

Comment: It is working now . Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using for loop on button_click method, which executes five times. So it is adding five text fields.

Remove for loop and this will app one text field on each button click. Also you need to define variables xaxis,yaxis in viewDidLoad method.

Updated code

```
@interface myController : UIViewController {
   float xaxis; 
   float yaxis;
   int i;
}
@end
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    xaxis = 60;
    yaxis = 130;
    i = 1;
}

- (IBAction)button_click:(id)sender
{
    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xaxis,yaxis,200,30)];
    textField.tag = i;
    textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    [self.view  addSubview:textField];
    yaxis = yaxis+50;
    i++;
}
```

Comment: What is `i`? This will put each new text field on top of the others.

Comment: Your update is still wrong. You still have an unknown variable named `i`. And you are now using unknown variables `xaxis` and `yaxis` in the `button_click` method.

Comment: Why do you think that you can use local variables from `viewDidLoad` in the `button_click` method?

Comment: @rma Ofcourse, we can't specify in viewDidLoad method. That should be declared in interface brackets.

Comment: And handle max textfields also.

Comment: @rmaddy Code Updated Now.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to remove the for loop.there is no need of for loop.Instead of that create a variable for count.and initialise it with 0 and create another one variable for Y axis.

For Ex:

```
var count = 0
var yAxis = 60
```

Then in the outlet action of button you need to create button programically

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,yAxis,200,30)];
```

Then you need to add this on to your view.

```
   [self.view  addSubview:textField];
```

Then you need to increase the height of yAxis.

```
yAxis = yAxis+60
count = count+1
```

Remeber to add the if condition for check the count

Comment: This is an Objective-C question. Answers should be in the appropriate language. You have half Objective-C and half Swift.